# How to duplicate Prestashop contact form page?

Tags: prestashop

I am using Prestashop 1.5 and want to clone Contact form page.

I tried it by myself, but no success. I duplicated  ContactController.php, contact-form.php, contact-form.tpl with different names, than new page appear in backoffice /seo and urls / created desired url, but if i try to access page with choosen url i get page not found.

Comment: Every thing seems fine. Try to regenerate htaccess for your site.
Also clear browser cache, and then try.
Thank you

Comment: i tried again, but the same problem :(

Comment: please enable errors in config/define.inc.php file and then check the page. If you saw any warnings, errors, please post them here. After that i can say something.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change the class name and the $php_self property to make it works.
If the class is not found, erase the /cache/class_index.php file.